# Is it a good coding practice to use Chrome DevTools to insert in-line CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

If inspecting and modifying my web page using Chrome DevTools, many people write some CSS to override existing CSS on a certain element,

For example,

style="border-radius: 0;" is added in. This can fix problems quickly, but is this a good coding practicing? Is it better to add the new css rule into CSS file instead?

I feel if overdoing this, later it would be kinda difficult to manage css on the site.

Comment: What do you mean? It's an excellent tool to tryout the CSS in live site, but still have to make changes in CSS file.

Comment: avoid inline styling when you can. Dev tools is for rapid development and debugging, but you should always put the finalized css in the correct file

Comment: It is _not_ a programming technique, so programming practise does not come into picture here.. It is just a handy tool for you to try out things on the fly

Comment: I'll second @ShivanRaptor's comment.  To expand it, the changes in Chrome DevTools aren't changes to the page, they're changes to the loaded, live, rendered representation of the page in the browser.  It doesn't change anything on the server.  It does NOT "fix problems" in the original source that created the page, it changes the current loaded live version of the page.  There is no relationship to what's on the server once it's in the browser loaded and running.  You cannot fix the source of the problem without "add(ing) the new ... rule into the CSS file.

Comment: I agree to make final changes in the css file. I just saw people inserting many inline styling in HTML after using DevTools, but not move those styles into css file later.

Comment: Those inline styles may not have been the right solution to the problem.  Many issues come from rule precedence issues, and many changes people make are exploratory, but when you look back at the source css you fine a more efficient or elegant way to achieve the "correct" result.

Answer (score 2):

The changes you make in DEV tools are not permanent. The changes will be reverted when you refresh the page. It's a good way to play around with and debug css, but it's not something you can do to permanently change your css.

I try to avoid inline styling because it makes it impossible to reuse your css, and it's not flexible if you want to change the theming of your site. If you instead do it in a stylesheet you can just swap out the stylesheet to give your site a new look.

Comment: It's the same thing as editing the html nodes inline in DevTools or entering javascript directly in the console, great exploration mechanism, but always a step in the process.  Do people use Chromes DevTools to directly edit the source files from file:/// urls?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice for quick debugging. However, once you found the right CSS for your layout, you shall modify your original CSS file.

Let us say you are developing a website for a customer. When they will want to make a modification, it will be far easier for the next developer if the CSS styles are in the right location.

It will be also very useful for you when you come back to this project after several months.

Comment: should?  I'd say: 'you *must* modify your original CSS file'

Comment: Haha, I concur, *shall* works great here :).

Comment: There are quite a bunch of "10 commandments of web developing" out there. Extract from: http://www.joomlaworks.net/blog/item/129-ten-commandments-in-web-development -> Avoid inline CSS like the plague. So it is indeed a _shall_ :) .

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `class` or `id` it is easier to read and  for contradicting objects and debugging. It will help with debugging knowing that that is not the defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a personal question but I will give you my thoughts on this matter anyways because I see this all the time.

DevTools is great for editing CSS on the fly and allowing you to play with possible changes to your site instantly.

However, I would not write entire CSS files in DevTools.  I write the bulk of my CSS in a text editor like Sublime Text and then test and play with it in Chrome and Chrome's DevTools.  It is easy to lose the changes you made in DevTools if you don't have it setup to save local copies and even then things can get very messy.